# Assigning a value to a List passed by reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to understand the following mechanism.

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("test");

NewLines(list);
Console.WriteLine(list.Count) // result is 1 not 0

ClearLines(list);
Console.WriteLine(list.Count) // result is 0

private static void NewLines(List<string> lines)
{
    lines = new List<string>();
}

private static void ClearLines(List<string> lines)
{
    lines.Clear();
}
```

If arguments in C# are passed by reference then why is the list not empty after calling `NewLines(list);`?

Comment: Because with `=`, you assign a new value to the parameter `lines`, not to the value that was passed to `NewLines`. What would you expect to happen if you'd have called `NewLines(new List<string>())`? You're looking for `ref`, and I'm sure there are plenty of duplicates that explain this.

Comment: Arguments are *not* passed by reference, why would you think so?

Comment: _"If arguments in C# are passed by reference"_ - they're not.

Comment: I guess the misconception is that not a copy of the list is passed, but a _copy of the reference to the list_. So it's actually not pass-by-reference.

Comment: Looking at it another way: you can change your local *reference* without affecting the outer *reference* (because of pass-by-value), but if you modify the original list you will see that on the outside, because the *reference* points to the same list

Comment: Please read https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 3):

Arguments are always passed by value unless the `ref` or `out` keyword is used. what's potentially confusing is that `list` *is* a reference (becasue `List<T>` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)). So when you pass in `list`, you're passing in the *value* of the reference. If you change it's value within the function, it's still just changing the *local* variable to a new list - it doesn't affect the passed-in variable.

So the change to get the code to behave how you expect is just to add the `ref` keyword:

```
private static void NewLines(ref List<string> lines)
{
    ​lines = new List<string>();
}
```

Although I would note that *returning values* is preferred compared to `ref` keywords

Comment: And in this case, using a Function to do this would be ... I'd say at least surprising, when you could just as well just do `= new List<string>();` directly.

Comment: But...don't do this outside of exploration.